# How to write only INFO logs in log file log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to write only `INFO` logs to the `logfile`, below is my `log4j` configuration

`log4j.properties` file is :

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE,
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs.out
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p - %m%n
```

Java file is:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jDemo {

    private static Logger log=Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("info");
        log.error("error");
        log.fatal("fatal");
        log.warn("warn");
    }
}
```

`logs.out` file is:

```
12 Apr 2016 15:38:35  INFO - info
12 Apr 2016 15:38:35 ERROR - error
12 Apr 2016 15:38:35 FATAL - fatal
12 Apr 2016 15:38:35  WARN - warn
```

Here I am getting logs in `logs.out` file are `INFO, ERROR, FATAL, WARN` but I want to write only `INFO` logs to `logs.out` file?

Anyone please suggest, how to achieve this objective?

my question is unique, it's not about **log4j logging hierarchy order** [log4j logging hierarchy order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745885/log4j-logging-hierarchy-order)

this shows the default configuration of `log4j` framework, but I want to implement the custom one, can you please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: So you don't want to see ERROR, FATAL, or WARN nor when they occurred?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j logging hierarchy order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745885/log4j-logging-hierarchy-order)

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442877/how-to-configure-log4j-to-log-only-info-messages-and-higher) might be in good help for you.

Comment: @javadev that's not my scenario, to show INFO and higher, i want only INFO logs

Comment: You need a [filter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html) then ... Scroll down to ThresholdFilter.

Comment: In Log4J older than 2.0 there is "LevelRangeFilter" (org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter) See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24932539/982149

Comment: But why would you ever want to hide _errors_? Program crashing and having error logs is a **good thing**.

Comment: @Tunaki Once I worked for a company where there were devs who blew out **any** log as ERROR. Things are not always used as intended ... so this is one reason to want this, that I have seen. OP may have completely different reasons, though.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the Filter you are looking for: org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter

**BUT** :

> "Note that filtering is only supported by the DOMConfigurator. The PropertyConfigurator does not support filters. "

(Source: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html)

So you'll probably have to switch to XML-Configuration-File.

For Log4j2 there is ThresholdFilter as already mentioned in the comments.